# Is it possible to get reference name for particular String in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to get reference name for particular String

EG. In one Android application string.xml contains for an UI

```
<resources>
    <string name="alpha"> ABC </string>
</resources>
```

Can I get resource reference "alpha"  for String ABC pragmatically from another app or same application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using reflection. Do note, however, that the following method does not account for resources with the same value.

```
private String getStringResourceName(String s)
{
    for(Field f : R.string.class.getFields())
    {
        try
        {
            int id = f.getInt(null);
            if(getResources().getString(id).equals(s))
                return f.getName();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

I've come up with a way to get the Resource name for a String value from an external package. In the following method, the first parameter is the package name - e.g. `com.mycompany.myapp` - and the second is the String value you're searching on. This method will return null if the search fails in any way.

```
private String getExternalStringResourceName(String packageName, String resValue)
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    try
    {
        Resources extRes = pm.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);

        String apkName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).applicationInfo.sourceDir;
        PathClassLoader pcl = new PathClassLoader(apkName, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Class resCls = pcl.loadClass(packageName + ".R");

        Class strCls = null;
        for (Class cls : resCls.getClasses())
        {
            if (cls.getSimpleName().equals("string"))
            {
                strCls = cls;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (strCls == null)
            return null;

        for (Field f : strCls.getFields())
        {
            try
            {
                int id = f.getInt(null);
                if (extRes.getString(id).equals(resValue))
                    return f.getName();
            }
            catch (Resources.NotFoundException e)
            {}
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {}
        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {}

    return null;
}
```

Comment: and one more query is if i want to get details from another application (package) what modifications do i need to do

Comment: This method iterates over the fields of the `string` class in the `R` class, looking for `static int`s (ignoring exceptions thrown otherwise), until it finds one that has a value corresponding to a String resource equal to the `s` parameter, then returns the field name.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure why you'd want to do this, but I've come up with a solution to your specific question. I've edited my answer to add it. Let me know if you've any trouble implementing it.

Comment: thanks @Mike this solution works. 
actually i was preparing one android tool for that this info was required.

Answer (score 1):

From an activity of the same applicatoin:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.alpha)
```

Comment: actually in my app i want that id by passing string means i should get alpha result by passing string "ABC"

Comment: why do you need this? what is your usecase?

Comment: sorry i cant give much application details but i want that reference name from string

Is there any way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for some set of strings (the method i am sharing is very inefficient.)
I have never tried it myself.. And it really seems to be useless.. The names of resources are specific to your app and retrieving such names from user input seems absurd.. can you specify your purpose?

Assuming you got the input from user and saved it in "mUserInput" string and have defined 
alpha, xyz , pqr and abc in your strings.xml , and you want to know name of the resource by searching the value of each string.
(in your question if you know ABC then you want to know the name of resource i.e. aplha)

Define a int array [since the resource ids are Integers (in R.java file) ]

```
private static final int mStringResourceArray[]{
                                             R.string.alpha,
                                             R.string.xyz,
                                             R.string.pqr,
                                             R.string.abc};
```

Define a method searchForResourceName(String tempUserInput):

```
private String searchForResourceName(String tempUserInput){

    for(int i=;i<=mStringResourceArray.length();i++){
            if(tempUserInput == getResources().getString(mStringResourceArray[i])
                    return mStringResourceArray[i];
            else
            return "No resource with the value given, found"

    }
```

Call the method :

```
String resourceName = searchForResourceName(mUserInput);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in this we need to know id so we can make "mStringResourceArray[]" and in my case i don't know id so i want to extract it

Comment: If it is a specific apk then you can open that apk in winZip or 7Zip and go to /res/strings.xml and know the value.

But the code i gave above wont work with this .. since the resource is in another app.. 

NOTE: This may be violation of someone else's Intellectual Property if you edit/copy their app without their consent ..